# Web components in lit-element + SASS

Tags: css, sass, styles, web-component

I'am developing some web components (I'm newbie) for an app with [lit-element] [1](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/) (Rather than [open-wc] [2](https://open-wc.org/)) and I want to create a "global default style" for my web components.

Could someone explain me concretely how to use SASS in a web component from scratch? I have read a lot of documentation, post and others, and nobody explains in a concise way how to do it (and everything I have tried doesn't work).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: edited for convert into a non opinion-based question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SASS (a file on your harddisk) has little to do with Custom Elements/Web Components (run in the Browser).

SASS needs/is a **pre** processor, to convert (compact) SASS syntax into CSS;
because the Browser only understands *CSS* and does **not** understand *SASS*.

It is then up to you how you want to deliver that **CSS** to the Client

For now you:

- Inject a text string `<style>[your CSS]</style>` in the Component HTML.
- Include the styles in a template, you `cloneNode(true)` into your Component:

```
      <template id="component">
          <style>[your CSS]</style>
      </template>
```

- (Nov-2020) In Chrome you can already use *Constructible/Constructable/Constructed* StyleSheets
  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/constructable-stylesheets

More:

- https://css-tricks.com/styling-a-web-component/
- https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/